# Identifying this IC marked 'IAANJ'

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification

Can anyone help me identify this IC?

It's inside a Camranger 2 next to a USB and ethernet port. It's overheating.

[image]

Comment: It may just be the lighting, but C837 looks suspiciously shiny to me. Can you check it with a multimeter to see if it is short-circuited? (The component identifiers are in that block of printing; for position, U22 is the IC in question.)

Comment: How do you know it is overheating? Did you measure it somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most likely an MP65151DJ from Monolithic Power Systems. For reference from the datasheet ([pdf](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MPS07272018_MP65150-1382652.pdf)):

[image: Screenshot of MP65151DJ datasheet, showing top marking information and pinout]

Note the top marking of "AAN" for an active-high single switch TSOT23-6 chip. Package information from MPS for a TSOT23-6 package ([pdf](https://media.monolithicpower.com/cms_document/Package%20Information/TSOT23-6%20TOP%20MARKING.pdf)) indicates that the vertical line is the polarity/pin-1 indicator, the first three letters are the package code, and the last letter is a date code.

[image: Top marking encoding schema from MPS document]

From an MPS document detailing the date code ([pdf](https://media.monolithicpower.com/mps_cms_document/t/o/top_marking_format_decoding_rule.pdf)), it looks like "J" means your part was made in 2018.

The circuit on your board seems to match the pinout as well (pin 2 = GND, pin 5 is a resistor to GND, pin 6 looks like an output with some output capacitance, etc.)

Comment: Many thanks! That's the one!